# Why is it 9 in Psych:9?

Tags: psych-9

Why is it **9** in [Psych:9](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0901504/)? I thought the film was a sequel to previous 8 films, but apparently there are no 8 prequels.

Comment: I've asked the director. Hopefully he'll be able to enlighten us :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Session 9](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0261983/) to [The Ninth Gate](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0142688/), and even pre-DVD with Dante's **nine circles of Hell**, it's a formidable number. Read more about number 9 and all its usage in culture and mythology [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9_%28number%29).

> Both movies, Session 9 and Psych:9, take place in abandoned (well in Psych: 9′s case, soon to be abandoned) hospitals and both have that **number 9** in the title that becomes a major plot point. Upon watching the film I was even more surprised how right I was as Psych follows the same formula as Session with much of the film being a supernatural thriller until the end.
>
> Roslyn (Sara Foster) is a sad woman who takes a job collating files for a soon to be demolished hospital. During her shifts she notices some strange occurrences such as ghostly figures and some mysterious singing. Roslyn is also grappling with the fact that she apparently can’t bear children, making her more on edge and putting her at odds with her husband Cole (Gabriel Mann).
>
> She eventually befriends the only other person working in the building, Dr. Clement (Cary Elwes), who works up on the fifth floor in the psychology ward. This particular ward is filled with many archaic, cruel looking devices, **especially room 9**.

Read the whole article [here](http://www.killerfilm.com/film_reviews/read/psych-9-review-screamfest-50332).

Comment: And not to forget [*Plan 9 from Outer Space*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Outer_Space). ;-)